How do we pull code into local main branch without having to commit the local changes afterwards?
I made some pull requests to a project I'm working on.  The owner of the project decided he wanted to create a new version release before merging my updates and he closed the previous pull requests.  He wants me to pull the new version into my local project and re-commit the changes and make new pull requests.
The problem I'm running into is after I created those initial pull requests I merged the code into my local main branch so when I run git pull there's quite a few merge conflicts that need to be resolved basically making my local main branch go backwards a few steps.  After I accept all the code coming from the remote branch git wants me to commit the changes made to all my files which doesn't make sense to me because all the code now matches the remote main branch.  The problem is the remote main branch is setup to block us from pushing code to it which of course is for a good reason but git won't allow me to complete the merging process until I commit the changes which means I can't begin rebasing the code into my feature branches.
Even when I unstage all the changes I still see a sync button in the toolbar that says there's 3 changes that need to be pulled into my main branch and 169 changes that need to be pushed to the remote branch.  How do I resolve this issue?

"After I accept all the code coming from the remote branch git wants me to commit the changes made to all my file" I'm not sure what you mean. Are you still talking about resolving the merge conflict from git pull? Merges are a commit; resolving a merge conflict ends with committing the merge.

"there's 3 changes that need to be pulled into my main branch and 169 changes that need to be pushed" This suggests you've made many additional changes to your main branch. Most Git tools present a simple, but false and misleading, linear history. To understand your issue, we'd need to see git log --graph --decorate --oneline. This will show the true history.

You've already merged your branch into main, and the "169 changes that need to be pushed" indicates you've made many more changes to main. You can't simply update your main and then create a pull request, there's too many other changes all tangled up.
We'll need to untangle just your original PR commits into their own branch on top of the latest upstream main. I'll explain.
The simple linear history presented on Github and git log is very misleading. Your repository actually looks something like this:
      3 - 4 - 5 - 6 [origin/main]
     / 
1 - 2 ---------- M - A - B - C ... [main]
     \         /
      Z - Y - X

You can see something like this with git log --graph --decorate --oneline, but rotated 90 degrees.
Commits 1 - 6 were made by the original project. You cloned at commit 2 and the project committed 3 - 6 since. You made a branch and committed Z, Y, X and made a pull request. Then you merged that branch back into main and have since made additional commits on top of that. Now Z - Y - X are buried under additional commits.
What we want is this...
                    Z1 - Y1 - X1 [your-branch]
                   /
      3 - 4 - 5 - 6 [origin/main]
     / 
1 - 2 ---------- M - A - B - C ... [main]
     \         /
      Z - Y - X

We want to rewrite your PR commits Z - Y - X on top of the new tip of the project's main as a new branch. Then that branch can be pushed as a PR.

First, git fetch origin to make sure your copy of the upstream repository is up to date; this won't affect any of your local branches. Then make a branch from origin/main and switch to it.
$ git fetch origin
$ git branch your-branch origin/main
$ git switch your-branch

      3 - 4 - 5 - 6 [origin/main][your-branch]
     / 
1 - 2 ---------- M - A - B - C ... [main]
     \         /
      Z - Y - X

Now copy your original commits with git cherry-pick. I've used Z - Y - X as placeholders. There's various ways you can get your original commit IDs. Simplest is to copy them from your original PR, even if it's closed.
$ git cherry-pick Z Y X

                    Z1 - Y1 - X1 [your-branch]
                   /
      3 - 4 - 5 - 6 [origin/main]
     / 
1 - 2 ---------- M - A - B - C ... [main]
     \         /
      Z - Y - X

There may be conflicts, resolve them normally. Now you can push your-branch and submit it as a PR.
